# Python 2.7.14--- importing vlc module on mac OS

Tags: python

in the last couple of days I was developing an APP on python IDLE.
I tried to import the vlc module, when I run it I get this error:
OSError: dlopen(libvlccore.dylib, 6): image not found

I installed the module with this command: pip install python-vlc.

I hope you can help me getting it work!
Thanks in advance!
Zaid Zaim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`python-vlc`](https://wiki.videolan.org/PythonBinding) is just Python bindings for [`libVLC`](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC/).

Without that library, it won't do you any good, because all it does is try to load that library (a `.dylib`, `.so`, or `.dll`, depending on your platform) and call functions out of it.

There should be installation instructions at the wiki page linked above, but on a Mac, the easiest way is to just install the VLC player. I know that if you install it with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), you get the library, in a location that `python-vlc` can find. But I think even the binary installer from the front page of [the main VideoLAN website](https://www.videolan.org/) will work as well.

If you're using Homebrew, you'll want to read the docs for when to search `brew` vs. `brew cask` vs. other taps,<sup>1</sup> or search somewhere like [Mac App Store](http://macappstore.org/vlc/) for the current status. But at present, the appropriate command appears to be:

```
brew cask install vlc
```

---

<sub>1. Generally, anything that you'd expect to find as a double-clickable app in `/Applications`, as opposed to a Unix command-line tool or a support library, is going to be a cask, and therefore in the tap `cask`, which has special shortcuts to access it. But that's a relatively new thing, and not every recipe has been converted yet.</sub>

Comment: Hey Thank you for your advice

Comment: After writing the command:  brew install vlc, I got this ERROR: Error: No available formula with the name "vlc" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
Can you recommend me an other thing?Thank you in advance!

Comment: @ZaidZaim I'll update the answer. It looks like what you want now is `brew cask install vlc`.

Comment: `brew cask install vlc`  is the only solution that worked for me

Comment: For updated systems: `cask` is no longer a `brew` command (https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/902). Use `brew install --cask vlc` instead. This also worked for me too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`brew install --cask vlc`

Is the latest command, and it works for me!